# How do you change the text color of a div based on its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm dynamically populating div text.
I want the text to change color depending on what the text is.

here's my js -

```
var BillView = Backbone.View.extend({

template:_.template($('#bill-view-template').text()),

tagname: 'div',

className: 'billView',

initialize: function(options){
    this.options = options;
    $('.ViewD').append(this.$el);

    if($('.vote').val('') === 'Yea' || 'Aye'){
        $('.vote').css('color', 'green');
    } else if($('.vote').val('') === 'Nay' || 'No'){
        $('.vote').css('color', 'red');
    }

    this.render();
},

render: function(){
    this.$el.append(this.template({options: this.model}));
},
```

})

```
<script type="text/template" id="bill-view-template">
        <div class='created'><%= options.get('created')%></div>
        <div class='bill'><%= options.get('vote').question %></div>
        <div class='vote'><%= options.get('option').value %></div>
    </script>
```

I'm only calling 5 objects at a time. the 1st 4 change to green, no matter the value. The 5th doesn't change at all.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. The option for specifying the view's element type is `tagName`, not `tagname`. You won't notice this mistake since `tagName` is `'div'` by default. I'd just leave it out completely.
2. `$('.vote')` searches the entire DOM for things with a `vote` class, it won't search just inside your view's `el` like it probably should.
3. `$(x).val('')` assigns an empty string as `x`'s value.
4. But `<div>`'s don't have values so that does nothing useful.
5. `$('.vote').val('') === 'Yea' || 'Aye')` is always true because

   1. It is parsed as `($('.vote').val('') === 'Yea') || 'Aye')`.
   2. `$('.vote').val('') === 'Yea'` is always false because `$('.vote').val('')` doesn't return anything useful.
   3. So the whole expression is just a complicated and confusing way of saying `'Aye'` and that string is true in a boolean context.
6. The `.vote` that you're probably looking for is not in the DOM until *after* `this.render()` has been called. So that whole `if` is in the wrong place.
7. The usual way of executing a template function in Backbone is to `this.template(this.model.toJSON())` and then you'd refer to `<%= created %>` in the template. This isn't necessary but it is a good idea to stick to the usual conventions so that other people can easily understand your code.
8. Usually the caller adds the view's `el` to the DOM so `$('.ViewD').append(this.$el);` would usually be somewhere else as `$('.ViewD').append(view.render().el)`.

I'd probably decide on the color inside `render` like this:

```
render: function() {
    var data = this.model.toJSON();
    data.voteColor = this._voteColor(data.option);
    this.$el.append(this.template(data));
    return this;
},

_voteColor: function(vote) {
    if(vote === 'Yea' || vote === 'Aye')
        return 'green';
    else if(vote === 'Nay' || vote === 'No')
        return 'red';
    return '';
}
```

and then the template would look like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="bill-view-template">
    <div class="created"><%= created %></div>
    <div class="bill"><%= vote %></div>
    <div class="vote" style="color: <%= voteColor %>"><%= option %></div>
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BJGF9/1/

You could also use:

```
_colors: {
    Yea: 'green',
    Aye: 'green',
    Nay: 'red',
    No:  'red'
},

_voteColor: function(vote) {
    return this._colors[vote] || '';
}
```

if you preferred a lookup table to an `if`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/atF3U/

In either case, you no longer need an `initialize` at all.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry I took so long to get back to you.